# Is it okay to update Google Cloud Messaging into lastest gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging only on the app side?

Tags: android, google-api, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am wondering if I can update from Google Cloud Messaging BaseIntentService APIs that are now deprecated into the new APIs, but only for the client side (on my application only).

Are the new APIs still compatible with the **server side old ones?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the new client APIs are compatible with the old server jar. The old server jar is not deprecated.
In fact, there is no new library for the server. Your server can communicate with either [GCM HTTP Connection Server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) or GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP). For HTTP you can keep using the old server library. However, if you want your app to send device to cloud messages to your server, you can't use the old library (since you'll need to use the XMPP protocol).